# WkLongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I dragged two gestures to my storyboard: One a tap gesture and the other a long press gesture.

Just to test it out, I set them up with something simple:

```
@IBAction func gestureDblTap(_ gesture: WKTapGestureRecognizer )  {

    print("hello world")

}

@IBAction func gestureHoldDown(_ gesture: WKLongPressGestureRecognizer ) {

    print("Holding down")

}
```

The double tap gesture works but the long press doesn't work. I've set it to 1 tap, 0.5 second and movement is 10.

I've implemented `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on iOS and it worked...I don't see why it shouldn't on `WatchKit`, since it's basically replacing `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with `WKLongPressGestureRecognizer`.

Any suggestion what I could try to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it by creating a Group and putting my gestures under that group:

```
@IBOutlet var gestureGroup: WKInterfaceGroup!

@IBAction func gestureDblTap(_ gesture: WKTapGestureRecognizer )  {

    print("hello world")

}

@IBAction func gestureHoldDown(_ gesture: WKLongPressGestureRecognizer ) {

    print("Holding down")

}
```

That worked.

[image]

The rest of the programming is just like in iOS.